# I couldn't run psql command in my ubuntu server (version 22.04)

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, psql

I couldn't run `psql` commad in my ubuntu server (version 22.04)

1. 1.I installed postgres with the command `sudo apy install postgresql-13`
2. Than I run `sudo -i -u postgres` to connect as user "postgres" and get this in terminal:. `postgres@IdeaPad:~$`. It's OK.
3. Next i try to run `psql` / `psql -h localhost -p 5432` and get an error message [image]
4. I made sure the postgres server is up [image]
5. I deleted file postmaster.pid and than restated the server [image]

   This don't solve the problem.
6. Changed file `/etc/postgresql/13/main/pg_hba.conf` to make it look like this[image]

   This don't solve the problem too.

I really don't understand what is problem and hope you could help me

UPD: I run `psql -U postgres -h localhost` and get this:[image]

Comment: 1) **DO NOT use images** copy and paste information as text. 2) If you want to see status of Postgres servers do `pg_lsclusters`.  The `postgres.service` is a just stub program that launches the actual ` postgresql@<*-*>.service`(s). The fact that  exited does not mean Postgres server(s) are not running. 3) `host` is for TCP connections. Given the comment lines you want `local`. 4) Did you reload the server after making the conf changes?

Comment: You will need a better description of what you did.  Ubuntu 220-04 doesn't come with an `apy`, and if you spell it `apt` then it can't find the package "postgresql-13".